# Глубокое копирование конструктора с помощью конструктора копирования на Java

Tags: java, ооп, конструктор, конструктор-копирования

В классе `Cat` имеется 3 конструктора:

```
public class Cat  {
    private double originWeight;
    private double weight;

    private double minWeight;
    private double maxWeight;

    private double weightFoodEaten;

    private static int count = 0;

    public static final int COUNT_CAT_EYES = 2;
    public static final double MIN_CAT_WEIGHT = 1000.0;
    public static final double MAX_CAT_WEIGHT = 9000.0;

    private Color catColor;

    public Cat() {
        weight = 1500.0 + 3000.0 * Math.random();
        originWeight = weight;
        minWeight = 1000.0;
        maxWeight = 9000.0;
        weightFoodEaten = 0;
        count++;
    }

    public Cat(double weight) {
        this();
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public Cat(Cat n) {
        weight = n.weight;
        originWeight = n.originWeight;
        minWeight = n.minWeight;
        maxWeight = n.maxWeight;
        weightFoodEaten = n.weightFoodEaten;
        count++;
    }
}
```

Конструктор  `Cat(Cat n)` является копией конструктора `Cat(double weight)`.

В классе `Test_2` я создаю сначала объект конструктора `Cat(double weight)` и потом его копию `Cat(Cat n)`.

Подскажите, почему не могу создать копию. Мне нужно именно создать копию с помощью конструктора копирования в классе.

```
public class Test_2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Cat bb = new Cat(5000);
        Сat cat7 = new Cat(Cat bb);
    }
}
```

Comment: А что по этому поводу говорят ошибки компилятора и IDE, пробовали читать? Как минимум при передаче не надо указывать класс еще раз `Сat cat7 = new Cat(bb);`

Comment: Сat cat7 = new Cat(bb);  Ошибка такая java: ')' expected

Comment: Значит вы где-то ошиблись пока копировали и добавили лишнюю скобку, поскольку больше ошибок нет. Ну еще почему-то в исходном сообщение и комментарии в слове Сat первая буква русская, а не английская, на что моя IDE тоже отругалась. Тоже проверьте этот момент `Cat cat7 = new Cat(bb);`

Comment: судя по ошибке, у вас закрытой скобки не хватает, но в целом для таких целей существует метод clone() , лучше используйте его

Comment: спасибо, ошибка была в том, что одну букву по русски написала.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем проблема вот в чем

```
Сat cat7 = new Cat(Cat bb);
```

здесь после открывающей круглой скобки нарушается синтаксис, и компилятор дальше не смотрит на оставшуюся строчку. Поэтому пишет, что нехватает закрывающей круглой скобки именно  в том месте, где возникает ошибка. Чтобы ее исправить, надо удалить оставшуюся часть строки и поставить закрывающую круглую скобку. Примерно так

```
Сat cat7 = new Cat();
```

Но это лишь исправит ошибку компиляции. Компилятор видит, что есть конструктор без аргументов и предлагает исправить ошибку вышеуказанным способом. Для того, чтобы воспользоваться другим конструктором, ему необходимо передать аргументом переменную.

```
Сat cat7 = new Cat(bb);
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное.